# How refer to specific ListItem inside DropDownList? How to modify DropDownList parameter programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

By selecting specific position (ListItem) in DropDwonList1 I would like to recall "if" which will change Visible parameter for "true" for DropDownList2.

In DropDownlist1 there is 4 ListItem elements with value = 1, 2, 3 and 4.

However by selecting specific position in DDL1... nothing is happening.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Label1.Text = "Nowa wartość";
    }
}
```

How to change DropDownlist Visible parameter to "true" (or false) by ButtonClick or DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged?

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
        DropDownList2.Visible = false;
        Label1.Text = "Nowa wartość";
    }
}
```

However, you need to set autopostback = true for the Dropdown1, else that code behind selected index changed will not trigger.